# Bash function that returns string of current UTC time echoes it and CWD and original filename

Tags: linux, bash, unix

Trying to return a string from `UTC()` bash function into `$SST` variable, and then print it with echo while also calling `cwd` when doing the echo.

```
#!/bin/bash

UTC(){ return "$(`date -u \"+%FT%TZ\"`)" }
SST="$(UTC)"; #ISO 8601 Script Start Time
owd="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )" #Path to THIS script.
me="$(basename "$(test -L "$0" && readlink "$0" || echo "$0")")"
echo -e "Started '$me' from '$owd' with 'cwd'='`$(cwd)`' @ $SST."
```

Comment: shell functions `return` exit codes. They need to `echo`/etc. output. That being said why does your `UTC` function return a command to run instead of just returning the output from that command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to return the command as a string; just execute the command directly.

```
UTC() { date -u "+%FT%TZ"; }
```

The current directory command is `pwd` not `cwd`. And you have both backticks `` `...` `` and `$(...)`. You only need one or the other.

```
echo -e "Started '$me' from '$owd' with 'cwd'='$(pwd)' @ $SST."
```

Finally, you could get rid of the quotes in the variable assignments if you wish. Strictly speaking they're not necessary, though it's not wrong to err on the side of putting quotes in if you're unsure.

```
SST=$(UTC)
owd=$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )
me=$(basename "$(test -L "$0" && readlink "$0" || echo "$0")")
```